# Falha ao tentar criar conexão pool node

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, typescript

estou tentando me abrir uma conexão pool utilizando o modulo oracledb mas recebo uma exception ao tentar criar a pool

```
import OracleDB from 'oracledb'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

OracleDB.outFormat = OracleDB.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT

dotenv.config()

export class BaseConnection {
  public connection: OracleDB.Connection
  public connectionPool: OracleDB.Pool

  public async openConnection (): Promise<void> {
    try {
      this.connectionPool = await OracleDB.createPool({
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        connectString: process.env.DB_CONNECTION_STRING
      })
      this.connection = await this.connectionPool.getConnection()
      console.log('Banco de dados conectado com sucesso')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

erro

```
{ Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in your PATH environment variable.
If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html
A Microsoft Visual Studio Redistributable suitable for your Oracle client library version must be available.

    at OracleDb.createPool (C:\Proc-evandro\ph\node_modules\oracledb\lib\oracledb.js:180:8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, este erro que esta retornando não explica qual o erro na conexão com o BD.
Esse erro é exibido quando você tem um erro que não esta sendo tratado, então primeiro você deve tratar esse erro, para que comece a ser exibido qual o problema de fato ao criar o pool.
Como você esta utlizando await pode capiturar o erro com try catch na hora de criar o pool, assim:

```
try{
  this.connectionPool = await oracledb.createPool({
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        connectString: process.env.DB_CONNECTION_STRING
  })
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Desse modo, quando der erro na hora de criar o pool, ele vai ser tratado no catch e no seu console será exibido o mesmo.
Se a saída do erro não for o suficiente para você resolver o problema com a conexão, edite a sua pergunte e inclua esta nova informação para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: fiz a alteração e recebi esse outro erro, detalha estou conectando em um banco de dados via VPN, tenho outra aplicação em node sem typescript que utilizo a mesma base de dados via pool conection e não recebo essa mensagem de erro.

Comment: @EvandroIgnacio, reparou que agora o erro está falando sobre a arquitetura 64bits? Chegou a fazer os procedimentos informados pelo próprio erro instalando a biblioteca em 64bits?

Comment: sim, a maquina host já tem ess configuração, eu utilizo o mesmo modulo em outra aplicação node sem typescript e a pool é criada sem erros, não entendo o porque recebo esse erro aqui

Comment: @EvandroIgnacio, uma coisa que você também deve reparar é que nesta aplicação você instalou o módulo nodedb localmente e não global, veja pela descrição do erro o caminho `C:\Proc-evandro\ph\node_modules\oracledb\lib\oracledb.js:180:8`, ou seja, se o oracledb esta local ele não deve estar "alcançando" o Oracle Client libraries, provavelmente nos outros projetos você utilizou este módulo global, sugiro que de uma lida em como deve ser utilizado/configurado o oracledb [aqui](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows)

Answer (score -1):

Eu enfrentei o mesmo empecilho ao subir um projeto no ambiente do cliente. O oracledb utiliza o client de 64 bits para conectar no banco. No meu caso bastou instalar o client disponível no próprio site da oracle que funcionou.